# VBA Move rows from one table to another based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 4 tabs: 1 main, daily updated tab, and 3 tabs that will store historical data.

There are various tables in each tab - I named all of them though.

Now, one of the tables in main daily updated Dashboard is called "Problems". The 6th column in this table is "Status". I need a macro that will automatically move the row of the data from table "Problems" to another table called "ProblemsSolved" in another sheet called "Problems" if the status of a problem is set as "Solved" or "Rejected"

Tables look like this:

[image: The main dashboard]

[image]

I have written a code already:

```
a = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current DMB Template").ListObjects("Problems").Range.Rows.Count


For i = 2 To a

If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current DMB Template").ListObjects("Problems").Cells(i, 6).Value = "Rejected" Or "Solved" Then

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current DMB Template").ListObjects("Problems").Rows(i).Cut

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Problems").Activate
b = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ProblemsSolved").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("ProblemsSolved").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Worksheets("Current DMB Template ").Activate
End If


Next
End Sub
```

But it gives me 438 error saying that the object doesn't support this method.

Help please, what am I doing wrong.

PS. it would be also great if you know the code for automatically moving the data up once the row is cut from the first table.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: A `ListObject` does not have a `Cells` method or `Rows` method. You'd either refer to `.Range.Cells` (which includes the table header), or `.DataBodyRange.Cells` (which excludes the header).

Comment: Also `A = x Or y` is improper.  One needs to use `A = x Or A = y`

Comment: Great!
Thank you.
But in this case, it will still take into consideration the table right? That is if the table expands for additional rows the macro will be valid still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be useful to use a few variables to make your code less repetitive and easier to maintain. Here's one approach:

```vb
Sub MoveClosed()
    Dim wb As Workbook, loOpen As ListObject, loClosed As ListObject
    Dim lr As ListRow, i As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'or ActiveWorkbook
    'get a reference to each of the tables...
    Set loOpen = wb.Worksheets("Current DMB Template").ListObjects("Problems")
    Set loClosed = wb.Worksheets("Problems").ListObjects("ProblemsSolved")
    
    For i = loOpen.ListRows.Count To 1 Step -1 'loop backwards
        Set lr = loOpen.ListRows(i) 'reference the row
        Select Case lr.Range.Cells(6).Value
            Case "Rejected", "Solved" 'move this row?
                lr.Range.Copy loClosed.ListRows.Add.Range.Cells(1)
                lr.Delete
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @Tim
Thank you so much it worked.
I am a beginner, self-taught in VBA and to be honest, I would never figure it out,
Just one correction that I made to your code:

`lr.Range.ClearContents`

works much better as the main Dashboard is a mess - tens cells merged come columns hidden, so with your code, once the row was deleted it looked like word document after pasting an image, with clearing the content it works a charm.

Once again many thanks!

Comment: Good to hear it worked out.